# GeoDjango tif import with "Raster needs to be opened in write mode to change values error"

Tags: django, raster, gdal, geodjango, postgis-raster

I am trying to import raster file to PostGIS via Django Shell. I create a class in my model, looks like that:

```
class MaxentModel(gismodels.Model):
    birdname = models.ForeignKey('BirdName', null=True)
    model_probability = gismodels.RasterField(srid=4326, null=True)
```

Then I want try to import first raster data with these commands from documentation (tried in Django shell):

```
>>>from validation_birds.models import BirdName, MaxentModel
>>>taxon_name_object = BirdName.objects.filter(name_cz='name of the bird')[0]
>>>rast = MaxentModel(birdname=taxon_name_object, model_probability='/path/to/file/picture.tif')
>>>rast.save()
```

But with rast.save() exceptions is raised and I get this error:

```
raise GDALException('Raster needs to be opened in write mode to change values.')
django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Raster needs to be opened in write mode to change values.
```

What does it mean that raster need to be opened in write mode and why GDAL wants change values (is it because of some setting)? How can I get over this error?

I cannot find some information about this exception so I will be glad for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found the solution. I was confused by documentation but is needed to create GDALRaster object and this object can be used for RasterField in geodjango. Here is a code:

```
>>> from validation_birds.models import BirdName, MaxentModel
>>> taxon_name_object = BirdName.objects.filter(name_cz='name of the bird')[0]
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALRaster
>>> gdal_raster = GDALRaster('pathtofile.tif', write=True)
>>> rast = MaxentModel(birdname=taxon_name_object, model_probability=gdal_raster)
>>> rast.save()
```